# Network MFP suggestion

Tags: networking, scanner, multi-function-printer

Can someone with personal experience recommend a network MFP for a small business? I am getting a little concerned about HP since they're really lagging on Windows 7 driver support for many of their MFPs and I find myself woefully ill-informed about other brands.

A nice plus would be the ability to send scans to a folder share on a server, but it's not necessary.

Wireless networking is a plus, but also not critical.

Cheers,

m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a little pricey, the [Xerox WorkCentres](http://www.office.xerox.com/multifunction-printer/color-multifunction/workcentre-7425-7428-7435/enus.html) are nice.  I'm running Windows 7 and I haven't had any issues with them.  They can also scan to email, shared folders, and FTP sites if you need.  I don't believe they can handle wireless networking out-of-the-box though.

[image]

Comment: Oh I would so love it, but, yeah, a little too pricey. :-(